# Cannot convert String to proper encoding format

Tags: java, encoding

To put it simply, I have to create a Java program that reads in lines from an input file and display the text read in a System.out statement. One of the lines in the file is **"Isn't it a bit"**. Java then reads this line as **"Isnâ€™t it a bit"**. The problem is that the apostrophe is being read as **"â€™"**. I've been looking at many forum posts and couldn't find a solution that would convert â€™ back into an apostrophe. I googled what "â€™" even is and it said it means the input is in UTF-8 format? How can I convert this to a format that will be read properly in a System.out statement.
Also, I can't just brute force a statement that converts all occurrences of â€™ into an apostrophe because there may be other UTF-8 encoding text that would cause problems so I can't just brute force every possibility.

Comment: What's the encoding used to create the file with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Windows-1252 encoding to read the file. There is good table here that shows the conversions between the two encoding standards. http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

The character isn't actually `'` but is actually a `’`. You can specify what encoding to use when reading a file. See the examples below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ReadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile();
    readFile.read("Windows-1252");
    readFile.read("UTF-8");
}

private void read(final String charsetName) throws IOException {
    //Java 8 version
    Files.lines(Paths.get("myFile.txt"), Charset.forName(charsetName)).forEach(System.out::println);


    //Older Java version
    final BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"), charsetName));

    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(currentLine);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you want to specify the encoding during file reading.

```
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("path"), "UTF-8"));
```